# Home Networking option - Wireless Switch

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking

We are trying to setup a small network setup. However, I do not have any wired connection in the room where lab is being setup. Right now I have a desktop which is connected through a WiFi adapter. What are the options I can use to setup my lab?

In my lab there is another desktop (ESXi host) couple of Cisco switches and Routers. I think what I am looking for is a wireless switch so I can connect my WiFi adapter to it and other devices to make it work as network.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly a good possibility would be to procure a Cisco 880 series wireless switch.  As you already have a couple of Cisco devices, you'd know that Cisco do a very wide range of reliable networking gear.  At home I am using a Cisco 887W-GN-A-K9 (Yes, I know it's a small business device, but I am a Cisco afficionado ...)

If you don't need Internet connection for your lab, then an 881W should work nicely as it is a Wireless 4-port 10-/100-Mbps managed switch (if you do want connectivity via WAN, then I can recommend 887W)

Either should be available from eBay or similar for a very good price - I picked my 887W up for example for 50,00 €.  If needed, I can also point you at a good source of good, solid, clean IOS images for the 880 series

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I think I was looking for option to bring internet into my room as there were no network port etc. That is resolved today by buying a set of Powerline adapter. Now can you please tel me if I can use that internet connection to Cisco1941 router and then to Cisco 2900 series to make it work as network or I need to have a small unmanaged. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I was able to assist :-)  even if only a little ... now - the 1941 has two 10/100/1000 Mbps ports and two High Speed WAN card slots ... so if I understand correctly, internet will come into your premises and into a router in another location.  That router will feed into a powerline adapter and then you'll pick up the signal from the other end of the powerline adapter in your lab.

Comment: I have used powerline adapters briefly, and from what I recall, the primary device must be plugged into Port 1 of the powerline router at the "receiving" end - so yes, you should be able to plug one of the 10/100/1000 ports of your 1941 into Port 1 (assuming it's a multi-port) of your powerline .... and then from your 1941 to your 2900 from the other 10/100/1000 ... love to hear how it goes